# How can I write tests to make sure celery tasks go into the right queue

Tags: python, testing, celery

Due to a complicated callback/chaining setup some tasks in our infrastructure seem to be going to queues that they were not assigned to. So I want to write automated tests to make sure that the celery task is sent to queue that it was specified to be handled by.

setup example:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery()

@celery.task(base=MyTask, queue='mytasks.add')
def add(x, y):
    a = x + y
    return a

@celery.task(base=MyTask, queue='mytasks.dadd')
def double_add(a, y):
    b = a + y

def caller(x, y):
    add.apply_async(args=(2, 1), kwargs={''callback': double_add.subtask(args=(3)) })
```

So here "add" should be handled by queue='mytasks.add', and "double_add" should be handled by queue='mytasks.dadd'

I understand basic result based testing for celery such as shown here: [How do you unit test a Celery task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078667/how-do-you-unit-test-a-celery-task)

But I would appreciate any insight into testing process for the above scenario.