# How to unit test code that runs celery tasks?

Tags: python, unit-testing, celery, pyramid, pytest

The app I am working on is heavily asynchronous. The web application runs a lot of tasks through celery depending on user actions. The celery tasks themselves are capable of launching further tasks.

Code such as the one shown below occurs in our code base quite frequently.

```
def do_sth():
    logic();
    if condition:
         function1.apply_async(*args)
    else:
         function2.apply_asynch(*args)
```

Now we want to start unit testing any new code that we write and we are not sure how to do this. What we would like to assert in our `pytest` unit tests is that we want to see if function1 actually got called. We do not want to necessarily run `function1` itself as we will have a unit test for the `function1`.

I do not want to be running celery as a process, neither do I want to run any AMQP broker during the unit test session.

Is this achievable?

**Edit**

It was pointed out that this is a duplicate of [How do you unit test a Celery task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078667)

It is not. Think about it. What I am asking is how to test if function has called **function1** through apply_async. That question is about how do I test **function1** itself. There is a major difference. I did hit that question before framing this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you unit test a Celery task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078667/how-do-you-unit-test-a-celery-task)

Comment: It's not a duplicate

Comment: I have seen that question and it is not what I am asking. If it isn't clear please ask more question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at the [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.mock.html) module which allows replacing functions you don't want to be invoked with "mocks" which look sufficiently similar to the original functions to convince the calling code that it's invoking the "real thing". You can then check that the mock was actually invoked and with what parameters. Example:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_do_sth():
    with patch('function1.apply_async') as function1_mock:
        do_sth()
        assert function1_mock.called
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `function1_mock.assert_called_once_with(*args)` to test the number of calls and if was called with correct arguments.

Comment: You can also use patch as a decorator for the test function (in this case, test_do_sth), which I prefer.

Comment: Does this still work?  I'm getting an AttributeError: apply_async raised in celery.local when mock tries to undo the patch after the test.  (That might be because I'm using @shared_task on my tasks.)